# What is meant by end of stream reached in inputstream.read()?

Tags: java, sockets

my android smartphone is tcpclient and chipkit wf32 wifi module is my tcp server.

```
int bytesRead;
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
     }
```

The above code reads the data from stream and copies to buffer. If no data is coming it will block. But sometimes i am getting -1. Can anyone explains the reason for getting -1? In document it is mentioned "end of stream is reached". But can you explain the meaning of that? thank you.

Comment: It means that your stream no longer contains any remaining data; you've reached the end of the stream.

Comment: what is meant by the end of the stream? Socket stream length is equal to the length of the data i send from the server. isn't it? if there is data in the stream, it should return the data. if no data is there, it should wait till data is received? Here how end of stream comes in to the picture?

Comment: @Kumar Can I have some money? What do you mean your wallet is empty?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you mean that the tcpserver doesnt have any more data to send and because of that inputstream on client side reaches the end of the stream?

Comment: @Kumar No. I mean the client says there is no more data to read.

Comment: Usually if there is no data to read. the inputstream.read() will wait for new data from the server. But may be in this case, client-server connection might be broken and because of that it is returning -1. Am i correct?

Comment: `byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8")` it that place in the code will cause problems with non ASCII characters, since it one unicode code-point may map to several bytes and those bytes might be split among several reads.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a socket, it means that the peer closed its end of the connection, or at least shut it down for output.

NB

```
response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
```

should be outside the loop. I've told you that before, in another of your numerous threads on this topic.

Comment: On my case the peer is wifi module which is the tcpserver. so you say the tcpserver closes the connection?

Comment: No, don't tell me what I said. I said the *peer* closed the connection. *If* you're the client, the peer is the server. If you're the server, it is the client.

Comment: Its wired. Once my module connected to the client. I am just sending the data. I will never call socket.close at any instant. and I am also logging the operation. In the log it never showed that the connection is closed during -1 scenario.

Comment: Nevertheless that is what it means. That and nothing else. Possibly you are unaware that closing a socket input or output stream closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: i got you point. stream is shutdown from the peer end. like socket.shutdown() function in winsock might be called by the server.

Comment: Or `close()`. I don't see why the server would log a socket close at all, so I don't understand why you're relying on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65799/discussion-between-kumar-and-ejp).

Comment: Nothing to discuss. The peer has either closed or shutdown the connection, regardless of what its logs may or may not say.